# fopen() with error on godaddy

Tags: php, fopen

I'm very new here but I'm facing an issue on one of my website with fopen().

```
$file="//".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/myfile".date("Ymd").".txt";
if (!file_exists($file)) {
 $fp=fopen($file,"w+");
}
$fp=fopen($file,"r+");
```

And the error message :

```
fopen(mydomain/myfile20160629.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or
directory in /mydomain/myphpfile.php on line 24
```

What's funny is that I sometimes get an error message, sometimes not, depending what file use this. And I still got this message when the file is created...

Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Try set path : `$file="//".$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/myfile".date("Ymd").".txt";`

but before that, move your file in directory `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

Comment: thanks but it still doesn't work, still the same error ... :(